# Como generar una variable de entorno PYTHONPATH para django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

Recientemente he actualizado mi Sistema operativo Ubuntu 14.04 a 16.04 y resulta que ya no puedo correr proyecto en Django que esta corriendo en un virtualenv me arroja este error.

```
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Como se puede regenerar el PATH de python?

Comment: Puedes compartir por favor, la versión de Django que estas usando, la versión de Python, y si luego de la actualización de sistema operativo volviste a instalar Django?

Comment: Estoy trabajando con Django10 en mi virtualenv, pienso que el problema es lo siguiente, cuando actualice ubuntu de 14.04 a 16.04, en el 14 python por defecto si no me equivoco tenia la version 2.7.6, y ahora por defecto lanza python 2.7.12.

Comment: ¿Pero tu proyecto en que versión de python estaba?, ¿2.7? he estado leyendo y preciso es algo que solo ha pasado en la versión de Django1.10, pero queria saber en que versión de python tienes el proyecto en un principio para intentar algo

Comment: En realidad Django lo tenia en mi virtualenv y lo único que hice es activar e intentar correr y me lanza el error

Comment: ¿No me puedes decir en que versión de python corrias el proyecto antes del error?

Comment: 2.7.6 de python tenia por defecto

Comment: puedes entrar a una shell de django e imprimir esto: `import sys; sys.path` me muestras por acá el resultado, y luego busca en tu directorio raiz del sistema (~) y busca entre las carpetas ocultas una con un nombre similar a `.virtualenvs` si usas virtualenvwrapper o si usas virtualenv normal, entra a la carpeta del entorno virtual y dame tu ruta absoluta a la carpeta de sites-packages que debe estar en lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: Al momento de entrar también al Shell de django me arroja el mismo error

Comment: Disculpa, no es la de django, es la de python normal

Comment: Si, el  PYTHONPATH para PYTHON requiero reconfigurar

Comment: ya lo estoy pensando formatearlo de cero..

Comment: no amigo, has lo que te dije en el otro comentario, pero desde la shell de python, es que creo que tu PYTHONPATH no tiene configurada la ruta a tu sites-packages, entonces se configura y listo. pero debes hacer la prueba, con tu entorno virtual activado

Comment: Intente hacer de todo, por no complicarme mas lo tuve que instalar de cero mi Sistema operativo, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En realidad solo había que reconfigurar el PYTHONPATH

Comment: A mi me pasó exactamente eso el martes pasado y se soluciona con una sola línea, pero no recuerdo exactamente cual. Es en realidad lo más fácil del mundo, porque lo que pasó es que cambiaron los enlaces al archivo `python` base.

Answer (score 1):

Te esta diciendo que Django no esta instalado en la versión de python que estas usando, supongo sera la por defecto, por lo que deberías instalar Django

```
pip install Django
```

prueba `python --version` para corroborar que es la versión con la que creaste tu virtualenv.

Alternativamente si tienes varias versiones de python funcionando puedes especificar que version de python quieres usar de la siguiente manera

```
 virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.6 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

Adicionalmente para ver los paquetes que tienes instalado en el entorno o en el virtualenv escribe:

```
$ pip freeze
```

Saludos